# Не работает onItemClickListener в ListView

Tags: android, listview

При нажатии на элемент списка ничего не происходит.
Код:
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MAIN ACTIVITY";
private Button buttonStart;
private ListView listView;
private MainListAdapter listAdapter;

private ArrayList<Paket> mList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    mList = new ArrayList<>();
    fillArray();

    listAdapter = new MainListAdapter(this, mList);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    initListener();

}

private void initListener() {
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Button pressed");
        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick()");
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LearnActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

private void fillArray() {
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        mList.add(new Paket());
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

MainListAdapter.java

```
public class MainListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private static final String TAG = "LIST_ADAPTER_TAG";
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<Paket> mList;


    Filter filter = null;

    public MainListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Paket> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mList = list;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_main, parent, false);
        }
        Paket paket = mList.get(position);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(paket.getmTitle());
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.description)).setText(paket.getmDescription());
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.count)).setText(paket.getmWordCount());

        ((Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnBuy)).setText(paket.getmPrice());

        return view;
    }

    private String getString(int position) {
        return ((String) getItem(position));
    }


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <Button
        android:text="НАЧАТЬ"
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="329dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:background="@color/colorGreen"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="3.0sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Назначать слушатели кликов для списков лучше в методе отрисовки элементов списка.

Вешание слушателя на сам список, при этом вызовет конфликт со слушателями самих элементов.

**Решение:**

Удалите слушатель кликов из активити и вешайте их на нужные элементы в методе `getView` адаптера.

Comment: Я бы тогда вообще советовал переходить с устаревшего ListView на более настраиваемый и новый RecyclerView. Он немного сложнее в освоении и не содержит нескольких очень удобных и доступных в ListView "из коробки" фич (таких как OnItemClickListener или заголовков), но зато намного более расширяем.

Comment: @xkor, таки да. Как я понимаю, постоянные вопросы по ListView связаны с обилием устаревших уроков в этих-наших-интернетах)

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам не нужно отдельно ловить клики по кнопке `btnBuy`, то добавьте для неё атрибут `android:clickable="false"` и всё должно заработать.

Comment: Нужно. Нужна обработка нажатия отдельно на кнопку и отдельно  на элемент списка.

Comment: вариант с android:clickable="false" не сработал